# xflock4 turns off the screen

Tags: xfce, lock-screen, 18.10, ubuntu-studio

Whenever my screen is locked, the monitor goes blank. If I input my password and log back in (or turn off my laptop with the power button), the monitor turns back on.

I once turned the monitor back on through key-mashing, but I don't know how exactly that worked.

Comment: It's not completely clear what your question is. Can you rephrase so that it's clear what you're asking for?

Comment: My monitor won't display the lock screen, so I have to enter my password completely blind. (I installed Ubuntu Studio to log in at boot so I don't know if this applies to the login screen as well.)

Comment: After a bunch of keyboard mashing, I logged out from my session and looks like it only applies to the lock screen. also, I was editing an image in GIMP and after I logged back in, I saw it was saved as my password after a crash.

Comment: I think this is related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519072/xflock4-lock-screen-will-shutdown